Does "...have recovered more than seven times of what they were..." have the same meaning as "...have recovered more than seven times what they were"?
From Why Grizzly Bears Are Still on the Endangered List

The grizzly bears in the greater Yellowstone ecosystem have recovered
more than seven times of what they were, and so Idaho, Montana, and
Wyoming have petitioned for the grizzlybears to be taken off the list,
and that is on the table right now.

In Two times of that price, Mahantongo said "Two times of that price is ungrammatical." So, is 'more than seven times of what they were' also ungrammatical? Or did he just omit 'the number'-'seven times [the number] of what they were'?

Yes, it is a mistake.

@Paul Tanenbaum Is the right version 'more than seven times what they were'?

"of" is used with fractions, but not multiples. I suspect the author took a sentence that originally had a fraction, replaced it with a multiple, and forgot to edit out "of".

E.g. "recovered more than one-third of what they were"

@Barmar If it's a fraction, it's out of context. He said there are now more than seven times as many grizzlies as before.

that's why it's a mistake.

@Barmar Is 'more than seven times what they were' proper?

yes of course it is

But "have recovered more than seven times what they were" would be better with "have recovered to more than seven times what they were."  We would say "The population has recovered to a healthy size" not "The population has recovered a healthy size."   This sense of recover, "to rebound from a distressed or unhealthy condition", is intransitive.

But we would say "The sick child has recovered a healthy complexion."  There the meaning is "to get something back, to regain something", and that usage is transitive.
